# Custom UIView as UITableView delegate and datasource?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uiview

I am writing a fairly complex iPad app - my first bigger one.

This app has some custom UIViews that present fairly complex data, including a table. These views do not take up the whole screen, and there can (and likely will) be many of them on screen at any time (though only one would be in an "expanded" state where the table is shown).

Here's a basic example that should convey the basic principle: [image: Made with the nice Antetype prototyping app]

Please note that these things are not supposed to be in popovers; instead, the FamilyViews expand to show their detailed data. (And please also note that this mockup was only created for the sake of this question and has little to do with how my interface is going to look; I know this is not good screen design)

**I'm undecided on who to put as the delegate and datasource of these custom views:**

- Making the **ViewController** for the current screen delegate and datasource is unelegant, because it's not just one table that's part of the VC's main view.
- Making the **View** itself the delegate and datasource seems a bit weird to me because it feels like giving the view too active a role; making it into a half-controller.
- Making the underlying **model object** the datasource seems too tightly coupled, and also breaks MVC. And it doesn't answer the question of who should be the delegate.

I'm tending towards making each of these "FamilyViews" delegate and datasource for their own tables. Action on these tables will have to be coupled to the FamilyView's delegate (the ViewController), but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?

**Anyone have some input on this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Views should know how to paint themselves and layout their sub views, depending on their properties, and that's it.

You definitely should let a controller class be the delegate instead of the view itself.

The delegate controller doesn't have to be the view controller that displays the view, though. It could easily be a completely separate controller class that only knows how to handle what the view requires.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd thought about that. So you're saying I should create a new class `FamilyMembersTableViewController` (that is not a viewController subclass) and instantiate that each time I need to display a new tableView? And this would act as a go-between for the `Family` model and `FamilyView`? This would keep MVC clean, but seems a little unnecessary, as the FamilyViews are awfully specialized anyway, and would be tightly coupled with their tableControllers.

Comment: I think a separate controller is the best solution. In ver. 2.0 of your app, you'll be implementing all this amazingly cool stuff, that would only make sense in a controller, and then you'll have to refactor. If you follow the MVC way of doing it now, you'll thank yourself later. :)

Comment: The more I think about this, the clearer it becomes that this is the way to go. I've implemented this, and it has no ill side effects. Thank you for helping me see the solution that should have been obvious :) (Though now I face an even harder problem: What should I name this class? To stay in the example, `FamilyMemberTableViewController` seems both obvious and confusing, since it is neither a `UIViewController` nor `UITableViewController` subclass, but it *is* a controller for a `UITableView`.)

Comment: Well if a `UITableViewController` is a controller for a `UITableView`, and a `UITableView` is a view for a table, then I'd suggest `FamilyMemberTableController`. :)

Comment: Yeah, that'll probably be the final name. Purely out of interest, though, is it the controller for the table, or is it the controller for a `UITableView`? Where does one start and the other end? Does UIKit even make the distinction?

Comment: A table view is a visual representation of a table. There's no distinction, so the controller manages the logic, that decides what the view will show.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and this nice discussion! Have a very nice weekend :)