# DBRestClient not working when called from an NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I'm fairly new to IOS and I'm now working on this big project that requires accessing files from storage channels like dropbox and googleDrive...

I managed to get to the dropbox files and manipulate them, but the problem is that I coudn't do that without having the DBRestClient property on the view class (`UITableView` in my case) which is not so MVC.

when I try to have it on another class, say an `NSObject` that implements DBRestClientDelegate, nothing happens.

I know that this problem has been posted before, and some says that the `NSObject` needs to have a strong reference to it so that it won't be deallocated, but I did just that and still nothing happens.

Here is some of my code:

The `NSObject` class DropboxServices

```
@interface DropboxServices : NSObject <DBRestClientDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, readonly) DBRestClient *restClient;


@implementation DropboxServices
@synthesize restClient=_restClient;
- (DBRestClient *)restClient {
    if (!_restClient) {
        if ( [[DBSession sharedSession].userIds count] ) {
            _restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
            _restClient.delegate = self;
        }

    }
    return _restClient;
}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

    NSLog(@"method called!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Here is the `UITableView` class that I used to have the DBRestClient in:

```
@interface DropboxFolderItemsTableView : UITableView 
@property (nonatomic, readonly) DropboxServices *dropboxServices;
```

but when I try to load metadata:

```
[[self.dropboxFolderItemsTableView.dropboxServices restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
```

nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 2 weeks with no response, I tried a completely different approach.
I found out an interesting fact at this post [Custom UIView as UITableView delegate and datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466892/custom-uiview-as-uitableview-delegate-and-datasource) and that is the delegate controller of each of my UITableViews doesn't have to be the view controller that displays it.

So I could just put my DBRestClient in a newly created viewController (or a tableViewController in my case dropboxFolderItemsTableViewController), and have a strong reference to it from my view controller that actually contains the table views, then assign the actual dropbox tableView (dropboxFolderItemsTableView) to be the table view of this newly created viewController.

```
self.dropboxFolderItemsTableViewController=[[DropboxFolderItemsTableViewController alloc]init];
self.dropboxFolderItemsTableViewController.tableView=self.dropboxFolderItemsTableView;
```

Comment: Im facing the same issue you are having although i don't think this solution clearly solves the MVC issue. I will look for a more appropriate solution one.