# Can a property of a UITableView be the UITableView Delegate and DataSource

Tags: ios, oop, uitableview

I have a custom view that's a bit of a hack. Basically it's a UIView with tableView as it's property, with additional views in the tableView that need their own delegates. I need a viewController for the UITableView and can't make the UIView it's delegate according to this SO link [Custom UIView as UITableView delegate and datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466892/custom-uiview-as-uitableview-delegate-and-datasource).

Can I make the UITableView have a property of UIViewController and set that UIViewController as the tableView's delegate?

In this case according to OOP, the UITableView *has a* UIViewController so technically, I could expect this to work. But, I am wondering if down the line somewhere this could create problems since the UITableView and UIViewController are coupled in this way.

Comment: You *can* have the view be the table view delegate and data source but it's just not best practice to do so.  In fact, you can make anything be the delegate and data source.  Just make sure it conforms to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `UIViewController` for the `UITableView` - you just need an object or objects that implement the  data source and a delegate protocols.  As per the accepted answer on the question you linked to you can use a separate controller class to provide this.

The right answer depends a little on how the table is used with your `UIView` subclass.

If the table will *always* have the same content (Say a list of months) and there is no value in exposing or abstracting the properties then you can code the delegate and dataSource inside your `UIView` subclass or in an assistant class.

If the table content will vary depending on how the `UIView` is used (say a list of people where you don't know what the list is - friends, relatives, employees...) then it would make sense to simply expose the tableview's datasource (and delegate if necessary) properties via your UIView subclass

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph you wrote. Why would the latter case be better that way? Essentially, I just want to init the view with a custom init(frame, info to load) and not expose anything else to outside objects except that.

Comment: It depends on whether your `UIView` is intended as a specific solution for your app (which it sounds like it is) or a reusable component - Remember, buttons, textfields and labels are all `UIView` subclasses, so just because you say it is a UIView doesn't mean that it isn't a re-usable component.  In my examples a list of months can be managed by a date picker itself but a `UIPicker` is more generic so it exposes properties that allow an another class to provide the data

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Is there any reason not to make the delegate object a property of the UIView for this project? Say for instance I just made an NSObject that is the tableView delegate as a property of the UIView because that's what works for this project.

Comment: You can do that, or you can just implement the delegate methods in your UIView subclass.

Comment: I guess to be more precise, is there any reason, theoretical or actual, why a UIView subclass should not be a UITableView delegate?

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from setting a UIView subclass as a delegate.  As for "theory" - it is all about your design - concepts such as abstraction, reuse and decoupling come into play.  If it makes sense for your design then do it.